# How to set the browser to open in Private window/Incongnito mode in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, the targeted browser can be configured for web apps. Anyone knows how to configure to open the browser in private window - Firefox and Chrome ?

Answer (score 7):

For Chrome you just need to open the Web Browsers section in Preferences and then edit the Chrome option. Set the Command line options to `-incognito` and Chrome should start in incognito mode. 
[image: IntelliJ WebBrowsers]

For Firefox I expect you need to start it in private mode. This URL starts Firefox on my Mac but I can't get it to work in IntelliJ

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -private
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the only one setup that worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what worked for me on MacOS Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

Chrome incognito

1. Check if `Allow in incognito` is switched on for `JetBrains IDE Support` extension (chrome://extensions/)
2. open WebStorm preferences -> Tools ->  Web browsers -> Chrome -> Edit -> Command line options: `-incognito`
3. Run Chrome incognito window manually